# SQL View does not accept Subclause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get a boolean field in a view from a string field in the table. The boolean field should be `True` if the string is filled:

```
SELECT (MasterId IS NOT NULL) AS HasMaster FROM entries
```

However, this causes the error:

> incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'

Why is that and how to fix?

Comment: You need to check it via case expression.

Comment: SQL SERVER doesn't have a boolean type. Try `CASE WHEN blah THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: Trying googling CASE WHEN Statement

Comment: T-SQL has boolean expressions, but those can never be used where a value is required, only in conditional clauses (`IF`, `WHERE`, `CASE`, etcetera). Yes, this is a defect in the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN MasterId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HasMaster 
FROM  entries
```

There is no Boolean values in `SQL Server`, so you can use `'0'` and `'1'` in `CASE` expression here.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN MasterId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) [HasMaster]
FROM entries
```

Answer (score -1):

Question: I need to get a boolean field in a view from a string field in the table. The boolean field should be True if the string is filled

Answer: use `case`

```
select case when MasterId is null then 0 else 1 end
from table_name
```

Comment: Strictly speaking `0`and `1` are **not** boolean values - at least not in the SQL standard. But as SQL Server does not support boolean values this is a workaround.

Comment: A tip, do not repeat the Question in the Answer, just the answer is enough.

Comment: What relevance does the youtube link have? I assume this is yours and you are trying to spam it?